# How to solve this problem when there is 15 number in list we find given number in slot 5 then print that slot also?

Tags: python, list

How to solve this problem when there is 15 number in list we find given number in slot 5 then print that slot also ?

Comment: kindly show the code that you have tried !

Comment: & you just search that number only at position 5th of the list ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, and sorry, but we aren't a code-writer service. Please share us, what have you tried (what's your [code](/help/reprex), if you've any)! If you haven't, search for a tutorial on another site, and come back to here with some code, what we can debug / help you get it working. Also read: [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Are you just searching for 5th number in a list of 15 numbers?

```
list = []
for i in range(15):
    i+=1
    list.append(i)
#above is only creating the list
print(list[4])#prints 5th entry in the list
```

if you want to know more about python arrays or similar:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp